# How do I make .htaccess redirect from a specific domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I had the following directive in a site's `.htaccess` file, at the root:

```
# redirect to contact page
redirectMatch 301 ^(/about)/?$ /contact/
```

However the site also hosts several other domains, which appear in the root folder as their own directories. For example, `http://mysite.com/anothersite/` displays the same thing as `http://anothersite.com`

Because of this, the redirect rule, as it is written, also redirects `http://anothersite.com/about/` to `http://anothersite.com/contact/`.

How can I rewrite the directive in the root `.htaccess` file so that it *only applies to*`http://mysite.com/about/`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*mysite.com.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(/about)/?$ /contact/   [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^about/? /contact/   [R=301,L]
```

The above will only work for mysite.com. To include all mysite sub-domains e.g. www etc and mysite.com use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?mysite\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^about/$ /contact/   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I modified the last rule to fix a typo and also include plain mysite.com domain. Let me know if the redirect works (run Fiddler etc to capture HTTP traffic). If not, there may be other rules in your .htaccess that could interfere - comment them all out and try this by itself to verify.